# angular-translate: How to translate a string with HTML formatting

Tags: angular-translate

I am looking to translate something like this using angular-translate:

```
All <strong>{{ itemsCount }}</strong> items are selected.
```

What is a recommended way to do this? I would like to avoid including HTML in the strings to be translated, if possible.

Comment: I suggest to translate static text with i18n that angular provides, because in each compilation will be static text as well and you will have a small and faster application. The best fit for the others options is dynamic translation.

Answer (score 0):

Angular-translate supports variables, so you could have a following translation key:

```
YOUR_KEY: "All <strong>{{itemsCount}}</strong> items are selected."
<p translate-value-count="{{itemsCount}}" translate>YOUR_KEY</p>
```

However that still requires storing HTML in translation. The only way you get around it is to use two keys instead:

```
ALL: "All",
SELECTED: "items are selected"
<p>{{ 'ALL' | translate}}<strong>{{itemsCount}}</strong>{{ 'SELECTED' | translate}}</p>
```

Comment: Practical experience from managing a codebase who used the two-key variant: If your text is a longer than a few dozen lines and requires HTML-formatting, **don't do this.** Someone who previously worked for my current project went with this solutions and now it is very expensive to manage and causes large translation files. For a long, static but formatted text, I would include the HTML in the translation file. If you need non-developers editing it, you can always use a .docx or markdown and convert that to HTML during compile time.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but for later readers:
With the keys separated you often cannot satisfy all language needs, because sometimes the parameter you want to insert belongs to a different place in the sentence in a foreign language! --> Hence I would store the whole sentence/text in the translation file with html tags. You can make use of them with the innerHtml attribute of the surrounding tag.
Additionally with this translation you would not handle the case of 0 or 1 selected item very well, as it comes out as: "All 0/1 items are selected".